# PCI header in my laptop looks different from free-electrons' PCI header

Tags: drivers, devices, pci

I'm trying to develope a pci driver but I can not compile it because my pci header is quite different from books and references. My distribution is 3.15.7-1-ARCH.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/pci.h

When the reference's pci.h looks complete, I can not understand why my laptop's header is just below:

```
/*
 *  pci.h
 *
 *  PCI defines and function prototypes
 *  Copyright 1994, Drew Eckhardt
 *  Copyright 1997--1999 Martin Mares <mj@ucw.cz>
 *
 *  For more information, please consult the following manuals (look at
 *  http://www.pcisig.com/ for how to get them):
 *
 *  PCI BIOS Specification
 *  PCI Local Bus Specification
 *  PCI to PCI Bridge Specification
 *  PCI System Design Guide
 */

#ifndef LINUX_PCI_H
#define LINUX_PCI_H

#include <linux/pci_regs.h> /* The pci register defines */

/*
 * The PCI interface treats multi-function devices as independent
 * devices.  The slot/function address of each device is encoded
 * in a single byte as follows:
 *
 *  7:3 = slot
 *  2:0 = function
 */
#define PCI_DEVFN(slot, func)   ((((slot) & 0x1f) << 3) | ((func) & 0x07))
#define PCI_SLOT(devfn)     (((devfn) >> 3) & 0x1f)
#define PCI_FUNC(devfn)     ((devfn) & 0x07)

/* Ioctls for /proc/bus/pci/X/Y nodes. */
#define PCIIOC_BASE     ('P' << 24 | 'C' << 16 | 'I' << 8)
#define PCIIOC_CONTROLLER   (PCIIOC_BASE | 0x00)    /* Get controller for PCI device. */
#define PCIIOC_MMAP_IS_IO   (PCIIOC_BASE | 0x01)    /* Set mmap state to I/O space. */
#define PCIIOC_MMAP_IS_MEM  (PCIIOC_BASE | 0x02)    /* Set mmap state to MEM space. */
#define PCIIOC_WRITE_COMBINE    (PCIIOC_BASE | 0x03)    /* Enable/disable write-combining. */

#endif /* LINUX_PCI_H */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free-electrons header is internal to the kernel source, and you will find it if you look in `[src]/include/linux`; if you are compiling kernel code, that  should be in play.

The header you've pasted is the system header, from `/usr/include/linux`.  That's for *user land* code that needs access to the constants and macros defined therein.

These don't actually conflict.  Notice at the top of the longer, kernel internal one:

```
#include <uapi/linux/pci.h>
```

That path doesn't exist in the normal system include directories, but it does exist in `[src]/include`, and if you check there for this file, you'll notice it's pretty much identical to your system's `/usr/include/linux/pci.h`.  That's how kernel code can access the same values, plus all the stuff it needs internally, since the usual `linux/pci.h` will have been overridden by something like `-I[src]/include`, but kernel code which contains `#include <linux/pci.h>` will pull in `[src]/include/linux/pci.h` which pulls in `[src]/include/uapi/pci.h` which is identical to `/usr/include/linux/pci.h`.